# How are identities verified on Atala Prism?

Tags: blockchain, atala-prism

I assume as an adult I can get an atala verified identity rather easily, but if a minor wants an identity on atala (for example, to play blockchain games) how is that done?  What information/documentation is needed, etc...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, Atala Prism uses paper-based credentials and plastic ID cards to identify users. In the case of minors, data from the server of the educational institution must be used as proof of their id. Data from the server can be transferred in `.csv` format.